# Remove Option from HTMLSelect in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, html-select

I am serving a webpage through a Google Apps Script but cannot remove an option from an HTMLSelectElement. When I call `select.remove(0);` by pressing the button, I get the error `'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'select.remove(0)')`. I am running Safari, but have also tried (with similar results) with Firefox. The code is below.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function removeFirstOption(){
      var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
      alert(select); //This returns "[object HTMLSelectElement]"
      select.remove(0);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
      <option value="nothing">Nothing to Display</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick="removeFirstOption()">Remove First One</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have also tried `.empty()`, but the same error is thrown.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: This fiddle works for me in Chrome. Does it work for you in Safari? http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/9z5rf/

Comment: It seems to work fine when the script is inline but not as a function.

Comment: @Blade0rz - Yes, that fiddle works for me, is there anything in GAS that would prevent it from working when displayed through HTMLOutputService?

Comment: Could you provide _minimal_ code to run this in GAS, please?